# Destroy Event generator object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have some object that generates an event in JavaScript.

I want to discard the object with events once an error occurred.

To be precise, the error is due to the disconnection of webSocket, and once the webSocket is disconnected, the event does mean nothing, so I want the object with event discarded.

```
        var __tl = someEventGenerator;
        __tl.onEvent(function(z)
          {
            try
            {
              // do some stuff
            }
            catch (e)
            {
              log('error');
              // if some error occured, stop event

              __tl = null;
            }
           }
```

I try `delete` statement for the  object property things etc, but nothing worked.

What is the most smart way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a variable in the global scope, then it is a property of the highest scope (in the browser, that would be `window`).

you could `delete window.__tl`, but fist you should remove all event listeners that may be bound to the object. Event Listeners are often overlooked, and they may keep a reference to your object (depends on the implementation).

Comment: Thanks. I will investigate.